# How to make items equal width after flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got this html snippet:

```
<div class="d-flex">
  // all divs inside are stage main containers
  <div class="stage-main-container">
  <div>
  <div>
  <div>
  <div>
  <div>
  // more items
</div>
```

CSS

```
.stage-main-container:first-child, .stage-main-container:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
}
.stage-main-container {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
}
```

First and last div are twice shorter than the middle ones. I need something like on the picture but to make first and last items the same width.[image] I was trying to set flex-grow but on flex wrap the items on the second row are too big. Also I've set min-width and max-width, but that's not my case: I need dynamic width

Comment: try min-width:0 on all the elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif, no it just shrinks them to a single row and the text overlaps each other, I need to save their width even on flex wrap so that they fill the whole (full) row